# Decode a textfile

Tags: c#, html, winforms

So I've loaded the following to a textfile which i then read into my c# program in a list, I then converted the list to a string. Now I want to decode the string from all HTML but I'm not able to. Someone now how?
Here is the text to format:

```html
<p> <span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Varifr&aring;n kommer den svarta m&auml;rren&nbsp; i Sm&aring;land?</strong></span></p>
  <p> <span style="font-size: 14px;"><input checked="checked" name="ruta1" type="checkbox" value="Svar 1" />&nbsp;Fr&aring;n Tyskland</span></p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" />Fr&aring;n Belgien</p>
      <p> &nbsp;</p>
        <p> <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Fr&aring;n Turkiet</p>
      <p>  &nbsp;</p>
   <p>  &nbsp;</p>
<p>  &nbsp;</p>
```

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string temp = "TextKod.txt";
        string line = "";
        List<string> texten = new List<string>();
        string vetEj;
        string hoppSan;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(temp);

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] myarray = line.Split('\r');
                vetEj = myarray[0];
                texten.Add(vetEj);
            }
            hoppSan = string.Join("\r", texten);
```

Comment: You want to *decode* or *encode*?

Comment: what do you want to end up with?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to remove all the html elements from the string and just replace with empty spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you *really want* is to *encode* the string. But either way, add a reference to `System.Web` and leverage the `HttpUtility` class. To decode:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString);
```

and to encode:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlString);
```

To get rid of all HTML elements, do this:

```
var cleanHtml = Regex.Replace(htmlString, "<.*?>", "");
```

You could modify the Regex to this `<.*?>|&.*?;` to get rid of those `&nbsp;` elements, but that also matches the `&aring;` in `Fr&aring;n Tyskland`, so that's up to you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to remove all the html elements from the string and just replace with empty spaces.

Comment: that got rid of all the <p> elements but there are still &nbsp in the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0+ you can also use [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmldecode.aspx) which does not require an extra assembly reference as it is available in the System.Net namespace.

this could also help

```
 myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string);
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to remove all the html elements from the string and just replace with empty spaces.